# if and else statement for bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a if and else statement for bash script.

**But some reason it's says command not found. So, what should i need to fix?**

Here is the code:

```
 echo "Please choose the following option: "
 echo "1: Make an New Folder"
 echo "1: Remove a Folder"
 echo -n "Enter the number: "
 read x

 if [$x -eq 1]: **command not found**
 then
   echo -n "Please Enter the New Folder Name"
   read New_Folder
   mkdir $New_Folder

 elif [$x -eq 2]: **command not found**
 then
   echo -n "Enter the Folder Name that you like to remove from the list: "
   read Remove_Folder
   rm-f $Remove_Folder
 fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `[` has to be followed by whitespace. It's a command name, not part of the `if` statement's syntax.